# Lattice like order on matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S denote the set of all square matrices of order n. Can we defined any order on S ? I am expecting a relation between matrices .

Comment: There are lots of ways to do (totally) order the set of all $m\times n$ matrices. Do you want your order to have some specific properties?

Comment: Yes, I want to know whether there is any lattice like order connecting two matrices

Comment: What do you mean by "lattice like" order?

Comment: A partial order on S or a subset of S.

Comment: What field are the entries in? Real numbers?

Comment: Yes, in the field of real numbers

Comment: In that case, then as I said above, there are infinitely many *total* orders on $S$. For example, here is a total order $\prec$ on $S$: Let $M\neq N$ be two matrices in $S$, and let $i$ be the least row index in which the rows of $M$ and $N$ are not equal. Let $j$ be the least column index in which the entries in row $i$ of $M$ and $N$ are different. Then set $M\prec N$ if $(M)_{i,j}<(N)_{i,j}$ and $M\succ N$ otherwise.

Comment: But, Casteels I couldn't read your answer properly as it includes other symbols. So please give your answer in the "Add an answer" area.

Comment: Casteels, I identified the option to read the content.